# skip presentOpenInMenuFromRect in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I want to share an image via whatsapp. 
I'm using UIDocumentInteractionController with the following code.
Can I skip the menu that is opened (and the user selects whatsapp) and just act as if he selected the first option?

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]])
            {
                NSString *savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];
                [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

                _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
                _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
                _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

                [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated: YES];


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**WhatsApp was updated with iOS 8 SDK** with `ShareKit` extension.
So now sharing to WhatsApp is 'default' in `UIActivityController` and there is no need to implement `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share the image.